# How to encode this map Map<int, List<int>>?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am having problems encoding this kind of map: *Map<int, List<int>>* blocksMap any suggestions how to do it? cause json.encode(blocksMap) gives an error *Converting object to an encodable object failed: _LinkedHashMap*

This is the example of data i'm trying to encode:

*Map<int, List<int>> blocksMap:*

```
{
0: [18, 117, 26, 200, 4, 30, 43, 110],
1: [18, 117, 26, 200, 4, 30, 43, 110], 
2: [18, 117, 26, 200, 4, 30, 43, 110], 
3: [18, 117, 26, 200, 4, 30, 43, 110], 
4: [18, 117, 26, 200, 4, 30, 43, 110], 
5: [18, 117, 26, 200, 4, 30, 43, 110], 
6: [18, 117, 26, 200, 4, 30, 43, 110], 
7: [18, 117, 26, 200, 4, 30, 43, 110], 
8: [18, 117, 26, 200, 4, 30, 43, 110], 
9: [18, 117, 26, 200, 4, 30, 43, 110], 
10: [18, 117, 26, 200, 4, 30, 43, 110], 
11: [18, 117, 26, 200, 4, 30, 43, 110]
}
```

Suggestions how to encode this map  would be great, Thanks!

Comment: I managed to solve the encoding part by changing the Map to Map<String, List<int>>

Comment: What problem do you then have? For your error, it is because JSON only allow `String` to be keys in maps. So since your data structure are using `int` as key values, it cannot be converted directly to JSON. You would therefore need to do some conversion of your data structure if you want to save it as JSON and convert it back again later.

Comment: Yeah when i changed the map key from int to string it started to work, so I solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your map to a Map of String and List of Strings

```
  final Map<String, List<int>> blocksMapOfIntToString = {
    for (var item in blocksMap.entries) '${item.key}': item.value,
  };
```

Then encode

```
  final encoded = jsonEncode(blocksMapOfIntToString);
```

And whenever you need your data, you decode

```
  final decoded = jsonDecode(encoded);
```

Then convert back

```
  final Map<int, List<int>> blocksMapOfStringToInt = {
    for (var item in decoded.entries)
      int.parse(item.key): List<int>.from(item.value),
  };
```

Comment: You don't need to also convert the `int` values inside the list. It is just keys in maps that must be `String`.